# Merging two audio streams from within a Transport Stream in ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, mpeg2, m2ts

I have an M2TS file which consists of the following:

```
Stream #0:0[0xc9]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv), 704x576 [SAR 16:11 DAR 16:9], max. 15000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
Stream #0:1[0xca](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 256 kb/s
Stream #0:2[0xce](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, mono, s16p, 64 kb/s (visual impaired)
```

I am trying to merge the two streams into a single one, but haven't had any success thus far.

I'd have thought that `-filter_complex "[0:1][0:2] join"` would've sufficed, but – whilst it appears to have merged the streams – I can only hear the audio from the first one.

I've tried using the `amerge` filter, but that constantly results in a memory allocation error, which is clearly spurious, since my machine has 16 GB of RAM.

Any help you could provide would be very much appreciated, as I am at wit's end!

Comment: Next time please provide the full uncut command line output of the conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there was one option I hadn't yet exhausted, and that was the `amix` filter!

This solved the problem:

```
-filter_complex "[0:1][0:2] amix=inputs=2[audio]" -map[audio]
```